# MongoDB with Java async driver: $lookup always empty

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have these two "linked" POJO entities:

```
public class User {
    public ObjectId id; // this is mapped to "_id" in the MongoDB
    public String userName;
    ...
}

public class Purchase {
    public ObjectId id; // this is mapped to "_id" in the MongoDB
    public ObjectId userId;
    public transient User user;

    public String productTitle;
    ...
}
```

The idea is to only persists the UserId for a purchase and load (or: JOIN) the appropriate User document on demand using the $lookup aggregate function. Because the Purchase.user property should never be saved in the MongoDB, it is declared as transient. Can this work?

Now, in my PurchaseRepository, I am trying to implement it like this:

```
public void getSinglePurchaseWithUser(Bson filter, SingleResultCallback<Purchase> callback) {
   Document match = new Document("$match", filter);

   Document lookupFields = new Document("from", "Users");
   lookupFields.put("localField", "userId");
   lookupFields.put("foreignField", "_id");
   lookupFields.put("as", "user");
   Document lookup = new Document("$lookup", lookupFields);

   List<Document> pipeline = Arrays.asList(match, lookup);

   AggregateIterable<Purchase> output = this.collection.aggregate(pipeline);
   output.first(callback);
}
```

Unfortunately, purchase.user is always empty in the result. I also tries a manual projection to explicitely read the user:

```
Document projectFields = new Document("_id", 1);
projectFields.put("userId", 1);
projectFields.put("user", "$user");
...
Document project = new Document("$project", projectFields);

List<Document> pipeline = Arrays.asList(match, lookup, project);
```

but this throws an error reading:

> org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: An
>   exception occurred when decoding using the AutomaticPojoCodec.
>   Decoding into a 'Purchase' failed with the following exception:
>
> Failed to decode 'user'. readStartDocument can only be called when
>   CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is ARRAY.
>
> A custom Codec or PojoCodec may need to be explicitly configured and
>   registered to handle this type.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

The first mistake was that the "as" fields has to be an array:

> Specifies the name of the new array field to add to the input
>   documents. The new array field contains the matching documents from
>   the from collection. If the specified name already exists in the input
>   document, the existing field is overwritten.

The other issue is that `transient` properties are neither serialized nor deserialized. A workaround for this is to mark the getter as @BsonIgnore but not the setter. This way, the property is skipped on serialization but not on deserialization.

```
public class Purchase {
    private User user;
    public ObjectId userId;

    @BsonIgnore
    public OrgenicUser getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(OrgenicUser value) {
        this.user = value;
    }
}
```

If you want to limit the array to one single object like in my case, you can use `$getElemAt` in your pipepline to pull the first entry like this:

```
Document lookupFields = new Document("from", from);
lookupFields.put("localField", localField);
lookupFields.put("foreignField", foreignField);
lookupFields.put("as", as);
Document lookup = new Document("$lookup", lookupFields);

// pulls the first match from the localField array
Document firstMatch = new Document(as, new Document("$arrayElemAt", Arrays.asList("$" + as, 0)));
// keep all fields and add/update the specified field
Document project = new Document("$addFields", firstMatch);
```